# Как не дублировать SVG?

Tags: svg

Имеем в резюме некое количество кода SVG который повторяется но стилизован по разному, вот пример :

```css
li{
list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>creative</span>
    <svg id="creative" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 332 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g transform="translate(27 -46)">
            <ellipse cx="-13" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="21" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="55" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="89" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="123" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="156" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="190" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="223" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
            <ellipse cx="257" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
            <ellipse cx="291" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
           </g>
          </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>teamwork</span>
    <svg id="creative" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 332 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g transform="translate(27 -46)">
            <ellipse cx="-13" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="21" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="55" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="89" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="123" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="156" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="190" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="223" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="257" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="291" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
           </g>
          </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>innovate</span>
    <svg id="creative" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 332 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g transform="translate(27 -46)">
            <ellipse cx="-13" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="21" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="55" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="89" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="123" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="156" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="190" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
            <ellipse cx="223" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
            <ellipse cx="257" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
            <ellipse cx="291" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
           </g>
          </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>comanication</span>
    <svg id="creative" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 332 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g transform="translate(27 -46)">
            <ellipse cx="-13" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="21" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="55" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="89" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="123" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="156" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="190" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="223" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="257" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#0000ffff"/>
            <ellipse cx="291" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" style="fill:#b3b3b3"/>
           </g>
          </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как можно без дублирования всего SVG в каждом новом списке по отдельности стилизовать каждый круг по разному сохранив такой же эффект но с меньшим количеством SVG?

Comment: создать верстку программно подходит?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  программно ? не знаю ....это как ? на PHP я могу это генерировать сколько требуется и без дублирования ...а вот на статике геморрой

Comment: програмно на клиенте, скриптом, если подходит - я оформлю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  в инспекторе будет куча SVG тоже , да ?

Comment: да, вы хотите меньше дом элементов?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  да ...именно так

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  и маленькое сорри ...я не папа Римский ...на Вы не надо

Comment: можно чтобы было по одному path на все фигуры одного цвета, или хитрости с clip-path и цветной подложкой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ты мне на тостере кое кого напоминаешь

Comment: еще можно все нарисовать на canvas и будет один элемент =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91385/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-maximlensky).

Comment: Зачем вам свг, только вот для такой формы? если да, то можно из дива сделать такую классом.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev да я знаю ...хотелось что то из серии "Ноу Хау" ..а дивами ни кого не удивишь щас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, если угодно вариант с 4 канвами

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

let data = [
  ["creative", 7],
  ["teamwork", 9],
  ["innovate", 6],
  ["comanication", 9],
];

data.forEach(block => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.append(li);
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = block[0];
  li.append(span);
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  li.append(canvas);
  canvas.width = 700;
  canvas.height = 60;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let i=0; i<10; i++){
     ctx.fillStyle = block[1]>i ? "#0000ff" : "#eeeeee";
     drawEllipse(ctx, i*68 + 30, 27, 30, 26);
  };

})

function drawEllipse(ctx, x, y, a, b) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.scale(a / b, 1);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, b, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте подробнее про **SVG спрайты**. Примерную суть я сейчас опишу, но больше можете поискать, информации по этому поводу куча.

Чтобы создать спрайт SVG нужно в начале кода(*есть вариант и с подключением внешнего спрайта, но тогда изменения при навидении например, или фокусе не будут работать*) создать скрытый элемент, например div с классом **hidden(display: none)** или можно на svg присвоить тот же класс и в него ставить тег **symbol** и присвоить ему **id**. Про него написал чуть ниже, подробнее можно узнать в поисковиках. И ещё нужно использовать тег **use с атрибутом href**(или xlink:href, это для кроссбраузерности) который будет **ссылаться на id** нашего тега **symbol**. С помощью **use** мы и будем обратиться к нашему спрайту. Пример кода приводил ниже.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 332 27" fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
    <g transform="translate(27 -46)">
      <ellipse cx="-13" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="21" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="55" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="89" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="123" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="156" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="190" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#0000ffff"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="223" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#b3b3b3"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="257" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#b3b3b3"></ellipse>
      <ellipse cx="291" cy="59" rx="15" ry="13" fill="#b3b3b3"></ellipse>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>


<p>teamwork</p>
<svg><use xlink:href="#svg"></use></svg>
<p>creative</p>
<svg><use xlink:href="#svg"></use></svg>
<p>teamwork</p>
<svg><use xlink:href="#svg"></use></svg>
<p>creative</p>
<svg><use xlink:href="#svg"></use></svg>
```

Элемент **<symbol>** предоставляет возможность группировать элементы. Можно выделить два основных приемуществ:

- Элемент <symbol> не отображается сам по себе. Этим он похож на .
- Элемент <symbol> может иметь собственные атрибуты viewBox и preserveAspectRatio. Это позволяет ему уместиться в области просмотра (viewport) так, как этого хотите вы, а не как это определено по умолчанию.

Comment: я прошу прощения , ну вот у вас явный косяк в SVG , У вас куча кружков и в каждом ряду ..три штуки другого цвета ...а надо что бы в каждом ряду было разное количество кружков ..про то как клонировать в svg я знаю